# Proving equality

Tags: integration

$$\left(\int\limits_0^1 \frac{dx}{(1-x^4)^{\frac{3}{4}}}\right) \left(\int\limits_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{\sin 2x}\ dx \right)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

I've made sub in the first integral:
$$z = \arcsin (x^2)$$ 
$$x^2 = \sin z$$ 
$$dz = \frac{2xdx}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}$$
$$dx = \frac{\sqrt{1-x^4}}{2x}dz=\frac{\cos z}{2\sqrt{\sin z}}dz$$
got this:

$$ \int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\int\limits_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sqrt{\sin 2x}}{\sqrt{2 \sin 2z}}dx dz$$

Comment: use the power of the incredible mighty beta function!

Comment: @tired: how can it be transformed to it?

Comment: @Mannix: many MSE users have already provided to you answers involving Euler's Beta function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), so that should not be a mistery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your claim is incorrect.
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(1-x^4)^{3/4}}=\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1}x^{-3/4}(1-x)^{-3/4}\,dx = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{\pi}}\,\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2\tag{1}$$
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\sin(2x)}\,dx = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\sin(x)}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}x^{1/2}(1-x^2)^{-1/2}\,dx \\= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}x^{-1/4}(1-x)^{-1/2}\,dx = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)2\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}\tag{2} $$
hence the product between $(1)$ and $(2)$ equals
$$ \frac{1}{2}\,\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\,\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2\sin\frac{\pi}{4}} = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}}.$$

---

Now a more fancy approach. It is enough to prove that $$\iint_{(0,\pi/2)^2}\sqrt{\frac{\sin u}{\sin v}}\,du\,dv =\pi\tag{3}$$
that is equivalent to:
$$ \iint_{(0,1)^2}\sqrt{\frac{u}{v(1-u^2)(1-v^2)}}\,du\,dv =\pi\tag{4}$$
or, by setting $T=(0,1)^2\cap\{v\leq u\}$, to:
$$ \iint_{T}\frac{\sqrt{\frac{u}{v}}+\sqrt{\frac{v}{u}}}{\sqrt{(1-u^2)(1-v^2)}}\,du\,dv = \pi \tag{5}$$
but the LHS of $(5)$, through the substitution $v=ku$, turns into:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{k}(k+1)}{\sqrt{(1-u^2)(1-k^2 u^2)}}\,dk\,du\tag{6}$$
so the claim also follows from [Legendre's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_relation) for complete elliptic integrals (i.e. from the fact that $K(k)$ is a solution of a peculiar hypergeometric differential equation).