# Solving $\int_0^{\frac\pi2} \sqrt{\sin(x)} dx \times \int_0^{\frac\pi2} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}} dx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I just came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4355953/show-that-int-0-frac-pi2-sqrt-sin-x-dx-times-int-0-frac-pi2-frac) answer and I am wondering why can't we change the product of integrals as a double integral.
$$\int_0^{\frac\pi2} \sqrt{\sin(x)} dx \times  \int_0^{\frac\pi2} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}} dx =\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\int_0^{\frac\pi2} \dfrac{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}\ dxdx = \dfrac{\pi^2}{4}$$
Why can't we do this?

Comment: Why would you be able to do this?

Comment: @Sorfosh I've been taught that it's a property.

Comment: Correct record is $\int \limits_0^{\pi/2} \int \limits_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(y)}} \, \mathrm{d} x \, \mathrm{d} y$

Comment: To compute this product of integrals probably the use of Euler Beta function will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

To echo [Ivan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/955514/ivan-kaznacheyeu), the concept is correct, but you're made a mistake. If you were to combine the integrals, you would have to change the variables since they aren't connected (they just happen to use the same letter). What you would end up with is
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt\frac{\sin x}{\sin y}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
$$
which evaluates to $\pi$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4355953/show-that-int-0-frac-pi2-sqrt-sin-x-dx-times-int-0-frac-pi2-frac?noredirect=1&lq=1) for the proof). The important thing to take note of is that even though the integrals use the same letter for their variable of integration, the variables are not the same, so when combining the integrals into a double integral you much change one of the letters